# Why is extracting an XML field value by property access not returning a value?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So, I have this XML: http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color_summarizer/?xml=1&url=http://i.imgur.com/I1phTe1.png&precision=extreme

I am trying to extract the `rgb` and its `avg` of `hex`. So in this case, it would be `d7dfe2`

As read from here:

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```
$feed = file_get_contents("http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color_summarizer/?xml=1&url=http://i.imgur.com/I1phTe1.png&precision=extreme");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);
echo $xml->imgdata->variable[9]->statistic[0]->hex;
```

However, it returns blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) passing suitable XPath expression to get that target text :

```
$feed = file_get_contents("http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color_summarizer/?xml=1&url=http://i.imgur.com/I1phTe1.png&precision=extreme");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);
echo $xml->xpath("//variable[@name='rgb']/statistic[@name='avg']/hex")[0];
```

brief explanation about the XPath expression :

- `//variable[@name='rgb']` : find `variable` element, anywhere in the XML document, having attribute `name` value equals `"rgb"`
- `/statistic[@name='avg']` : from such `variable` elements find child element `statistic` having attribute `name` value equals `"avg"`
- `/hex` : from such `statistic` elements, return child element `hex`

Comment: That's... new. Thank you I did not know that.

Comment: But why does the original code 'not work'? Are such dynamic properties and access not supported with simplexml? Or is there an error with the form used, and if so what?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $xml->imgdata->variable[9]->statistic[0]->hex;
           ^^^^^^^
```

That is where you’re going wrong – `imgdata` is the root element of your XML, so your `$xml` variable “points” to that already.

```
echo $xml->variable[9]->statistic[0]->hex;
```

– that will get you the output `d6dfe2`.

---

Using `var_dump` instead of `echo` will get you

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "
d6dfe2
"
}
```

– so you see it is still a `SimpleXMLElement` object, and the node value includes the whitespace that is present within the original XML data. So you might want to additionally cast that to a string and trim it, before you process it any further:

```
trim((string)$xml->variable[9]->statistic[0]->hex)
```